# Calculating averages of a set of integers on a line in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, average

Could anyone help me out with this, I have a listbox that looks something like this

```
    Oranges 8,2,7
    Apples 0,10,3
    Pineapples 6,9,1
```

And I basically want to be able to calculate the average value for each line and display it at the end of the line on a button press. I have the code for calculating the average of the entire listbox but can't figure out how to do it for each line, I was thinking of putting the correct code into a loop and I have a feeling I would have to use the string.parse method in order to separate the numbers by the ','?

Comment: You can use a For each loop to get every line of the ListBox. Then you can use the String-Method "Split" to split the line in two parts by the blank. After that split the second part you just got again - but this time by the comma. You should have a String array with the three numbers then. Use Integer.Parse(...) to cast the strings to an Integer, so you can sum them up and calculate the average. If you get stuck just post your code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a control (ListBox) as your place to state data, it's just for showing it to the user. The information in the ListBox must have come from somewhere. You should store the information in a form that suits what you want to do with it. In this case you seem to have a list of things that consist of a string and some numbers, so how about a class with a string property and another property that is a List (or Array) of Integer. Alternatively, a Dictionary(Of String, Integer()) would store this information for you.

Comment: @JanTheGun That sounds good but the problem is the numbers aren't stored in arrays, the numbers in the listbox are read from a file and will change. Also if you didn't mind would you be able to post how I would start it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blackwood suggested you can (and should) store your fruit data in a separate class. Here I added a summary function which you can use for your ListBox later...

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Fruit

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal numbers As List(Of Integer))
        _name = name
        _numbers = numbers
    End Sub

    Private _name As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _numbers As List(Of Integer)
    Public Property numbers() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return _numbers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
            _numbers = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Function to calculate the average of the numbers
    Public Function getAverage() As Double
        If _numbers.Count = 0 Then
            Return 0
        End If

        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For Each num As Integer In _numbers
            sum = sum + num
        Next
        Return sum / _numbers.Count
    End Function

    'Function to get a summary of the fruit for the ListBox
    Public Function getSummary() As String
        Dim summary As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        summary.Append(_name & " ")
        For i = 0 To _numbers.Count - 1
            If i = (_numbers.Count - 1) Then
                summary.Append(_numbers(i) & " ")
            Else
                summary.Append(_numbers(i) & ",")
            End If
        Next
        summary.Append("Average: " & getAverage())
        Return summary.ToString
    End Function

End Class
```

When pressing a button you read your text file, split the lines and put the values in a list of Fruit objects:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim inputLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\data.txt") 'Read all lines of the text file

    Dim fruits As List(Of Fruit) = New List(Of Fruit) 'Create a new list of fruits
    For Each line As String In inputLines
        Dim namesAndNumbers As String() = line.Split(" ") 'Split the line to get an array (of size 2) with the name and numbers
        Dim name As String = namesAndNumbers(0)
        Dim numbers As String() = namesAndNumbers(1).Split(",") 'Split the second element of the array to get the numbers as array

        'Convert the numbers from String to Integer
        Dim numberIntList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
        For Each number As String In numbers
            numberIntList.Add(Integer.Parse(number))
        Next

        Dim fruit As Fruit = New Fruit(name, numberIntList) 'Create a new Fruit object and add name and numbers
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fruit.getSummary) 'Add the summary of the Fruit object to the ListBox
    Next

    'Do whatever you want with the list of fruits ...
End Sub
```